# How do I make my html object-to-table array script run faster? (Pandas)

Tags: python, performance, html, pandas, iteration

I have a data frame that has several columns, one of which contains html objects (containing tables). I want a column of table arrays.

My problem is that this piece of code takes a long time to run. Is there any way I can optimize this? I tried list comprehension, which doesn't significantly improve run time.

Some suggested that I restructure the logic. Any suggestions how?

```
    df = htmldf
    countries = dict(countries_for_language('en'))
    countrylist = list(countries.values())
    arrayoftableswithcountry = []

    arrayofhtmltables = []


        for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            #print("We are now at row ", idx+1, "of", len(df),".")
            inner_html = tostring(row['html'])
            soup = bs(inner_html,'lxml')
            tableswithcountry = []
            outputr = []



            for idex,item in enumerate(soup.select('table')):
                #print("Extracting", idex+1, "of", len(soup.select('table')),".")
                table = soup.select('table')[idex]
                rows = table.find_all('tr')
                output = []
                outputrows = []

                for row in rows:
                    cols = row.find_all('td')
                    cols = [item.text.strip() for item in cols]
                    output.append([item for item in cols if item])

                if methodsname == 'revseg_geo':
                    if '$' in str(output):
                        for country in countrylist:
                            if country in str(output):
                                tableswithcountry.append(output)
                                outputr.append(table)


            arrayoftableswithcountry.append(tableswithcountry)
            arrayofhtmltables.append(outputr)

    df['arrayoftables'] = arrayoftableswithcountry
    df['arrayofhtmltables'] = arrayofhtmltables
    print('Made array of tables.')
    df.drop(columns=['html'])
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show an example of the data you're processing.

Comment: Your question as posted is borderline off-topic. (For our "unclear what you're asking" reason.) Questions on Code Review must contain a description (in English) of what your code is doing. I wanted to edit your title to resolve BCdotWEB's comment, however you've not provided me with the information to do so.